# Botão responsivo e centralizado

Tags: javascript, html, css

Gostaria de uma ajuda para fazer um botão ficar sempre no centro da minha box de código, de maneira responsiva.

Estou construindo uma landing page em um construtor de sites chamado Zyro, nele eu tenho a opção de adicionar elementos em código, o problema é que eu não consigo de forma alguma fazer esse botão ficar centralizado verticalmente na box de código, fiz várias tentativas e o máximo que consegui foi fazer o botão ficar centralizado horizontalmente.

Segue meu código atual:

```js
document.getElementById('randomButton').onclick = function() {
  window.open('https://google.com', '_blank')
}
```

```css
div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1em 1.8em;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #303030;
  background: #000000;
  color: #00F498;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.2s;
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Rubik";
  font-weight: 900;
}

button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #00F498, 0 0 25px #00BCAA, 0 0 50px #00F498;
  transition-delay: 0.6s;
}

button span {
  position: absolute;
}

button span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, #00F498);
}

button:hover span:nth-child(1) {
  left: 100%;
  transition: 0.7s;
}

button span:nth-child(3) {
  bottom: 0;
  right: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, #00F498);
}

button:hover span:nth-child(3) {
  right: 100%;
  transition: 0.7s;
  transition-delay: 0.35s;
}

button span:nth-child(2) {
  top: -100%;
  right: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, #00F498);
}

button:hover span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 100%;
  transition: 0.7s;
  transition-delay: 0.17s;
}

button span:nth-child(4) {
  bottom: -100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(360deg, transparent, #00F498);
}

button:hover span:nth-child(4) {
  bottom: 100%;
  transition: 0.7s;
  transition-delay: 0.52s;
}

button:active {
  background: #00F498;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #00F498, #00BCAA);
  color: #bfbfbf;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px #00F498, 0 0 8px #00BCAA, 0 0 8px #00F498;
  transition: 0.1s;
}

button:active span:nth-child(1) span:nth-child(2) span:nth-child(2) span:nth-child(2) {
  transition: none;
  transition-delay: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik">

<div>
  <button id="randomButton">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span> Comece Agora!
    </button>
</div>
```

[Box de código - Zyro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaNj9.png)

Não sei bem como essa box de código do site funciona, acredito que ela faça uma função de 'div', mas posso estar falando besteira.

Sou novo no meio da programação, resolvo muitas coisas na tentativa e erro, mas gostaria de entender a solução para poder caminhar com as próprias pernas nas demais situações do dia-a-dia.

Se alguém puder me ajudar a resolver e conseguir explicar a resolução de uma forma que um novato entenda, ficarei muito grato!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Para você colocar o elemento centralizado de forma vertical no HTML com css, existe duas forma para centralizar um elemento no centro tanto vertical quanto horizontal.

Com `flex box` e `position`

1⁰ com position

```
div {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100vh;
   position: relative;
}

button {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   padding: 1em 1.8em;
   outline: none;
   border: 1px solid #303030;
   background: #000000;
   color: #00F498;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   letter-spacing: 2px;
   font-size: 15px;
   overflow: hidden;
   transition: 0.2s;
   border-radius: 20px;
   cursor: pointer;
   font-family: "Rubik";
   font-weight: 900;
}
```

2⁰ com Flex box

```
div {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100vh;
}

button {
   transform: transition;
   padding: 1em 1.8em;
   outline: none;
   border: 1px solid #303030;
   background: #000000;
   color: #00F498;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   letter-spacing: 2px;
   font-size: 15px;
   overflow: hidden;
   transition: 0.2s;
   border-radius: 20px;
   cursor: pointer;
   font-family: "Rubik";
   font-weight: 900;
}
```

Aqui testei e funcionou, espero que tenha ajudado.